# Json.net passing parent instance when deserialising hierarchy

Tags: serialization, constructor, arguments, json.net, parent

When JSON.NET deserializes an hierarchy it does so top to bottom, that means it first does the parent and after that the children of that parent but how can I have JSON.NET pass that parent to the child constructor? It feels wrong to have a second pass to 'fix it up' afterwards or to extend/override stuff for this is just contextual stuff.

Example snip, public Child(Parent parent) gets a null for Parent but I would like to have the real parent there that JSON.NET created prior to constructing the children:

```
class Parent
{
    list<Child> Children;
}

class Child
{

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        // 
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems

        [OnDeserialized]
        public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
        }

will do it for me, assuming it will, consider this one answered by me.

Comment: could you add a real answer with an example to this thread? I'd like to see the answer more clearly